# How to center a label in a tkinter colspan using grid?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to center the "This should be in center" label on my python numberpad I made with tkinter and grid.

Currently, it looks like this:
[The label is not in center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdOWo.png)

I've tried to add `anchor=CENTER` to the attributes of the label, but it made no change.

Here is the relevant code for the numberpad:

```
class App:
numdigs = 0
def __init__(self, root):
    frame = Frame(root)
    grid=Frame(frame)
    b = Label(root, text="This should be in center")
    b.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
    b = Button(root, text="1", width=10, command= lambda *args: self.setVar(1))
    b.grid(row=1, column=0)
    b = Button(root, text="2", width=10,command= lambda *args: self.setVar(2))
    b.grid(row=1, column=1,)
    b = Button(root, text="3", width=10,command= lambda *args: self.setVar(3))
    b.grid(row=1, column=2,)
    b = Button(root, text="4", width=10,command= lambda *args: self.setVar(4))
    b.grid(row=2, column=0,)
    b = Button(root, text="5", width=10,command= lambda *args: self.setVar(5))
    b.grid(row=2, column=1,)
    b = Button(root, text="6", width=10,command= lambda *args: self.setVar(6))
    b.grid(row=2, column=2,)
    b = Button(root, text="7", width=10,command= lambda *args: self.setVar(7))
    b.grid(row=3, column=0,)
    b = Button(root, text="8", width=10,command= lambda *args: self.setVar(8))
    b.grid(row=3, column=1,)
    b = Button(root, text="9", width=10,command= lambda *args: self.setVar(9))
    b.grid(row=3, column=2,)
    b = Button(root, text="*", width=10,command= lambda *args: self.setVar("*"))
    b.grid(row=4, column=0,)
    b = Button(root, text="0", width=10,command= lambda *args: self.setVar(0))
    b.grid(row=4, column=1,)
    b = Button(root, text="#", width=10,command= lambda *args: self.setVar("#"))
    b.grid(row=4, column=2,)
```

Can you help me get back on track here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the label in column 1 and told it to span two columns. Therefore it is in column 1 and column 2.

I assume you want it to span all three columns, so the solution is to move the label to column zero and have it span three columns:

```
b.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily solve with this

```
lbl_address = ttk.Label(addmission_form,text="Address")
    lbl_address.grid(row=7,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
    txtBox_address = ttk.Entry(addmission_form ,width=100)
    txtBox_address.grid(row=7,column=1,columnspan=3,padx=40,pady=10)
```

the out of this code will be this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQBmx.png)